# Using ToolStripMenuItem shortcuts in C#

Tags: c#, shortcut

I have a menu item to open a file. This item should be selected by typing the letter "o" or be activated by typing the keys Ctrl+O.
So I created the following object:

```
fileOpenMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem();
fileOpenMenu.Name = "fileOpenMenu";
fileOpenMenu.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.O;
fileOpenMenu.Text = "&Open...";
fileOpenMenu.Click += new EventHandler(FileOpenMenu_Click);
```

If I go to the menu then there is the letter "o" displayed in the right of the open item. Is this correct? I expected that the text "Ctrl+O" is displayed on right side because this shortcut is defined.
Is there a way to automatically show the shortcut text instead of the access key letter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting hotkey/shortcut text next to toolstrip menu items in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322077/putting-hotkey-shortcut-text-next-to-toolstrip-menu-items-in-winforms)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `fileOpenMenu.ShortcutKeyDisplayString` to the string value you desire to appear.

More info in [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322077/putting-hotkey-shortcut-text-next-to-toolstrip-menu-items-in-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

I have a ToolStripMenuItem with a Ctrl + O shortcut. I see "Ctrl + O" as text in the menu item. This should be the default behavior.

My code looks like this:

```
menuItem.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.O;
```